# Add Blank Item to devexpress aspxlookup Control

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have this databound devexpress 7.1 aspxlookup control, and I'm trying to add a new item at the top and set the selected index to that item. For the life of me I cannot add a new item in the code behind, but I can add one in the init script in the markup.

I cannot however set this as default item. I'd love to be able to just do all this in the code without having to get involved in the javascript side of things.

Any suggestions?